# flowtype cannot return object literal because object type is incompatible

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, types, flowtype

I have the following types:

```
export type Transaction = {
  amount: number,
  description: string
}

export type TransactionsForMonth = {
  month: number,
  year: number,
  transactions: Array<Transaction>
}

export type TransactionsGroupedByDay = Array<{
  date: string,
  transactionsForDay: Array<Transaction>
}>

export type TransactionsForMonthGroupedByDay = {
  month: number,
  year: number,
  transactionsForMonth: Array<TransactionsGroupedByDay>,
}
```

I've created a function that converts from `TransactionsForMonth` to `TransactionsForMonthGroupedByDay`, by reducing over the transactions and sorted them into days:

```
transactionsGroupedByDay ({ month, year, transactions }: TransactionsForMonth): TransactionsForMonthGroupedByDay {
  // transactions are already sorted in date order
  const transactionsGroupedByDay: TransactionsGroupedByDay = transactions.reduce((transactionsGroupedByDay, transaction) => {
    const thisDay = transactionsGroupedByDay.find(({ date }) => date === transaction.transactionDate)
    const transactionsThisDay = thisDay ? [...thisDay.transactionsForDay, transaction] : [transaction]
    return [
      ...transactionsGroupedByDay.filter(({ date }) => date !== transaction.transactionDate),
      {
        date: transaction.transactionDate,
        transactionsForDay: transactionsThisDay
      }
    ]
  }, [])
  return {
    month,
    year,
    transactionsForMonth: transactionsGroupedByDay
  }
}
```

When I run flow over this function, I get the following error:

```
Cannot return object literal because object type [1] is incompatible with TransactionsGroupedByDay [2] in array element
of property transactionsForMonth. [incompatible-return]

     src/api/services/TransactionService.js
     55│     return {
     56│       month,
     57│       year,
     58│       transactionsForMonth: transactionsGroupedByDay
     59│     }
     60│   }
     61│

     src/api/types.js
 [1] 35│ export type TransactionsGroupedByDay = Array<{
     36│   date: string,
     37│   transactionsForDay: Array<Transaction>
     38│ }>
       :
 [2] 43│   transactionsForMonth: Array<TransactionsGroupedByDay>,
```

I am new to flowtype and am wondering what this error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is basically saying, the function is supposed to return an object of a given type structure, but your return statement doesn't satisfy that requirement.

The reason for that is because in `type TransactionsForMonthGroupedByDay` you've declared that the property `transactionsForMonth` is an array of `TransactionsGroupedByDay` but the variable you actually pass into `transactionsForMonth` you've declared as `const transactionsGroupedByDay: TransactionsGroupedByDay` which is incompatible.

You can fix this by either fixing your type to accept a single `TransactionsGroupedByDay` or your variable declaration needs to return an array of `TransactionsGroupedByDay`.

Comment: Thank you! That was such a simple inconsistency that I had completely missed.